# Laravel 4, Retrive morphed Parent Model, querying child

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphism

I didn't know how to ask the question so, the question is not as clear as the description. But here it goes.
I want to query the parent Model, by quering the child Model. Here is the basic Models:

```
    //Gig.php
    class Gig extends Eloquent 
{
    public function gigable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('profile');
    }
}

//Band.php

class Band extends Eloquent {
public function gigs()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Gig','profile');
    }
}
//Musician.php

class Musician extends Eloquent {
public function gigs()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Gig','profile');
    }
}
```

Now, I know I can do something like this:

```
Gig::find(1)->gigable
```

Is there a way that I can retrieve gigables in one query
and for example for my api I can return all the gigable at once.
Something like:

```
Gig::where('id','>',1)->gigable
```

I know thats doesn't work. 
Such as in reverse of this I can do something like,

```
Band::with('gigs')->where('created_at','<',Carbon::now())->get();
```

Comment: are you sure about your relations? From the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations), you are confusing PROFILE and GIGABLE

Answer (score 0):

Use as follows

```
//Gig.php
class Gig extends Eloquent {
    public function gigable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

//Band.php
class Band extends Eloquent {
public function gigs()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Gig','gigable');
    }
}

//Musician.php
class Musician extends Eloquent {
public function gigs()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Gig','gigable');
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to get the gigs this way:

```
$band = Band::with('gigs')->where('created_at','<',Carbon::now())->get();
$gigs = $band->gigs;
```

If this is what you wanted... your question is unclear